# JavaScript returns NaN only in Google Chrome, works fine in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am trying to change the width of a div using jQuery. It should change proportionally to a value inside another div.

I am using the following script:

```
var maxWidth, maxCount;

$('.view-most-commented ul li').each(function(i) {

var $this = $(this);

var thisCount = parseFloat($this.find('.comment-bar').html());

if ( i == 0 ) {

maxWidth = $this.width();

maxCount = thisCount;

}

var thisWidthStr = (thisCount / maxCount) * maxWidth;

var thisWidth=parseFloat(thisWidthStr);

$this.find('.views-field-comment-count').attr('style','max-width :'+thisWidth+'px');

});
```

This works just fine in FF, but in Chrome the value of `thisWidth` is a NaN.
Any idea what could be causing the problem?

As suggested in the comments below, I tried finding out the value of each variable.
The output in Chrome is:

```
thisCount:NaN
maxWidth:0
maxCount:NaN
thisWidthStr:NaN
thisWidth:NaN
thisCount:NaN
thisWidthStr:NaN
thisWidth:NaN
thisCount:NaN
thisWidthStr:NaN
thisWidth:NaN
thisCount:6
thisWidthStr:NaN
thisWidth:NaN
thisCount:5
thisWidthStr:NaN
thisWidth:NaN
thisCount:5
thisWidthStr:NaN
thisWidth:NaN
thisCount:5
thisWidthStr:NaN
thisWidth:NaN
thisCount:4
thisWidthStr:NaN
thisWidth:NaN
```

While the ouput in FF is:

```
thisCount:6
maxWidth:955
maxCount:6
thisWidthStr:955
thisWidth:955
thisCount:5
thisWidthStr:795.8333333333334
thisWidth:795.8333333333334
thisCount:5
thisWidthStr:795.8333333333334
thisWidth:795.8333333333334
thisCount:5
thisWidthStr:795.8333333333334
thisWidth:795.8333333333334
thisCount:4
thisWidthStr:636.6666666666666
thisWidth:636.6666666666666
```

Comment: Check to see the value of `thisWidthStr` just before assigining it to `thisWidth`. May be that can help find the cause

Comment: General tip: You could use Chromes console and try your code line by line and see where Chrome is choking on.

Comment: Check the value of each variable involved using `Console` or `alert`..

Comment: @clyde lobo, @felix kling, @shadow wizard ... the console output for each variable is : thisCount:NaN
maxWidth:0
maxCount:NaN
thisWidthStr:NaN
thisWidth:NaN
thisCount:NaN
thisWidthStr:NaN
thisWidth:NaN
thisCount:NaN
thisWidthStr:NaN
thisWidth:NaN
thisCount:6
thisWidthStr:NaN
thisWidth:NaN
thisCount:5
thisWidthStr:NaN
thisWidth:NaN
thisCount:5
thisWidthStr:NaN
thisWidth:NaN
thisCount:5
thisWidthStr:NaN
thisWidth:NaN
thisCount:4
thisWidthStr:NaN
thisWidth:NaN

Comment: @vr3690 : ist basically because you get `NaN` for `thisCount`. Have you declared/initialised `thisCount` before using it ? What's the value for it when viewed in FF ? 
Putting up the HTML code or a demo on jsfiddle.net  may also help.

Comment: @clyde lobo : `thisCount` is initialised using the following statement - `var thisCount = parseFloat($this.find('.comment-bar').text().toString());` .. the value of `thisCount` in FF is 6. You can check out the test page at http://testcheckchecktest.whackk.com/grab/frontpage.html

Comment: Silly question.. do you have this code inside `$(document).ready` function? Also, put your HTML code so that we can try and reproduce it..

Comment: @Shadow Wizard : yes, it's inside `$(document).ready`. follow this link for the full html code  - testcheckchecktest.whackk.com/grab/frontpage.html

Comment: ok. so it seems i got the problem. it's not javascript or chrome. it's bloody stupid me. it seems drupal (my CMS) was adding an extra 3 `li`

Comment: @vr3 cheers, wonder why it happens only in Chrome though??

Comment: @Shadow : because I was logged on as the admin in Drupal. i really need to kill myself now.

Comment: @vr3 lol hope you'll do it softly.. :)

Answer (score 0):

i'm thinking maxcount = zero. the reason being is any number divided by zero will result in a NaN, since it's mathematically impossible.

Comment: maxWidth is 0. but then, thisCount and every other variable is a NaN. check out the console.log outputs I added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

```
var thisCount = parseFloat($this.find('.comment-bar').html());
```

into:

```
var thisCount = parseFloat($this.find('.comment-bar').text().toString());
```

Comment: does not help. The problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$(function () {
        var total = 0;
        var all = $('.most-commented li');
        for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
            total += parseFloat($(all[i]).find('.comment-count').text().toString());
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
            var count = parseFloat($(all[i]).find('.comment-count').text().toString());
            var per = count / total;
            $(all[i]).find('.comment-bar').css({ width: per * 400 });
        }       
});
```